# Unable to add technical profile "PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify" under display control "ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile". when try get below error

Tags: xml

getting below error.

2023-06-26T05:17:50.2543349Z {"error":{"code":"AADB2C","message":"Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_PASSWORDRESET_US_EXP" of tenant "manpowergrouptalentdev.onmicrosoft.com".Technical profile 'PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify' is not supported as validation technical profile of Display Control 'verifyEmailOrPhoneControl'.Technical profile 'PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify' is not supported as validation technical profile of Display Control 'verifyEmailOrPhoneControl'.","innerError":{"correlationId":"fc4a4754-3b8e-4cb2-86df-b3c9e4998349","date":"2023-06-26T05:17:49","request-id":"4afdf67a-806f-4be8-b5a8-d1748ecc67f2","client-request-id":"4afdf67a-806f-4be8-b5a8-d1748ecc67f2"}}}
2023-06-26T05:17:50.3280397Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

enable call button along with text for phone factor.

-->
              
                
                  
                    mfaType
                    email
                    SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.